# ngFor looping incorrectly - adding value to each and every row as a pose to the specific row

Tags: angular

I am trying to display data from an array in my HTML template but my looping is not working ccorrectly. My code will explain it a bit better.

Here is a stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

```
<div class="flex-grid padding-5" *ngFor="let f of files_dropped">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
      </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row equal">
        <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
        <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.type }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
        <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.size }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row equal" *ngFor="let d of dimensions">
        <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ d.width }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
        <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ d.height }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


onSelect(event) {
  const ctx = this;
  const dim = this;
  dim.dimensions = [];
  ctx.files_dropped.push(...event.addedFiles);
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < ctx.files_dropped.length; i++) {
    
    formData.append("file[]", ctx.files_dropped[i]);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      const img = document.createElement("img") as HTMLImageElement;
      img.onload = () => {
        console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        dim.dimensions.push({"width": img.naturalWidth, "height": img.naturalHeight});
      }
      img.src = reader.result as string;
    }, false);
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(ctx.files_dropped[i]);
    console.log(ctx.files_dropped);
  }
}
```

So essentially this is what is happening. The loop is adding the `dim.dimensions` to each image row. Everytime I add a new image it adds the new dimesions to all the image rows. The 200 width, 200 height should be there for the first image but not the second. The 553 width, 550 height should be there for the second image but not the first. Any ideas please

[image]

Comment: Can you share code somewhere?

Comment: @VaganM. here is a stackblitz of my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Comment: I can't see any relationship between a file and its dimensions, i would focus on that task first, right now it seems that for all files you are displaying all images dimensions.

Comment: @SGa yes the File does not allow me to add the dimensions inside of that array hence I had to separate them. Please see my stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-dropzone-mg6mrz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get dimension for file. so I delete dimensions Iteration and get index from files_dropped Iteration to use it for get dimension per file.

```
    <div class="custom-dropzone" ngx-dropzone  (change)="onSelect($event)">
      <ngx-dropzone-label>
        <div>
          <h2>Drop your files here</h2>
        </div>
      </ngx-dropzone-label>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-grid padding-5" *ngFor="let f of files_dropped let i = index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
          </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.type }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.size }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ dimensions[i].width }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ dimensions[i].height }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="flex-grid padding-5" *ngFor="let f of files_dropped; let i = index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
          </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.type }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.size }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ dimensions[i].width }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
            <div class="col justify"><ngx-dropzone-label>{{ dimensions[i].height }}</ngx-dropzone-label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```